# std::string to LPOLESTR

Tags: c++, string, com, ole

I have an array of strings like this:

```
using std::string;
string myArray[] = { string("abc"), string("foo"), string("muh") };
```

Now I want to use this function:

```
HRESULT Init(T* begin, T* end, IUnknown* pUnk, CComEnumFlags flags = AtlFlagNoCopy );
```

T is in my case LPOLESTR. So I need to convert the array of std::string to LPOLESTR respectively I need an LPOLESTR* to begin and end of this array. How is that done?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ATL has a [set of macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for string conversions. In your case, you can use:

```
LPOLESTR olestr = A2OLE(std_str.c_str());
```

Note that OLESTR is basically a wchar_t*, so if you're using std::wstring (or wide char string literals) you don't even need the macro:

```
LPOLESTR olestr = std_wstr.c_str();
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but i'm also trying to convert a std::string to LPOLESTR and when I try this code i get "identifier _lpa is undefined". I've included atlbase.h and atlconv.h. Also in the doc you linked from what I can tell it looks like A2OLE is designed to convert a LPSTR to LPOLESTR (is this why we use c_str?). I'm completely new to c++ so excuse me if i'm missing something obvious, would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: @rhowell - I haven't touched COM stuff since around the time I wrote my answer, so might be missing something too. The `_lpa` error can be solved by adding the `USES_CONVERSION` macro before using the conversion macros (yuk!). In general, those macros convert between wide chars and regular chars. The ATL string types depend on the build (Unicode/ascii), so converting to/from regular C/C++ types (which don't depend on the build) must depend on the build too. The `c_str()` is used to gat a raw C string, namely pointer to chars array, as the macros aren't meant for C++ std::string objects.

Comment: eran means to put this line `USES_CONVERSION;` inside the function, before any conversion call. I misunderstood its meaning for the first glace and eventually worked with it